# $f:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ injective but not surjective

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, analysis, functions, differential-geometry

I thought this question was trivial, but I actually can't answer it, I hope I'm not missing something important.

Let $S^1:=\{z\in \mathbb{C} \textit{ such that } |z|=1\}$.

Can there be an injective continuous function $f:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ which is not surjective?

Then this question generalizes to:

Consider $M_n$ a n-dimensional differential compact manifold. Can there be $f:M_n\rightarrow M_n$ continuous and injective but not surjective?

Comment: I hope you mean a _continuous_, injective function? Also, some times it definitely works, because you can map $\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^n$ by $(x_1, x_2, \ldots,x_n)\mapsto (\arctan(x_1), x_2,\ldots,x_n)$. Perhaps you want to limit this to _compact_ manifolds? Then I suggest you look at the concept of the [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping) of a continuous function.

Comment: to find a counterexample, try a function $f:S^1\to S^1$ that is not continuous.

Comment: @Arthur yes, I mean continuous and injective, I corrected it

Comment: Would this still be not true if $f$ is just injective and not continuous?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible, an injection would define an homeomorphism on its image (here I use compactness of $S^1$), and there is no subset of $S^1$ homeomorphic to $S^1$.

Comment: Thank you. This argument should be valid also for any closed oriented surface, right?

Comment: Sure, I even think with homology you can prove it for any compact oriented manifolds.

Comment: For functions which are only injective (not continuous) this would still be true?

Comment: @user294185 : no, consider the map $f : S^1 \to S^1, e^{i\theta} \mapsto e^{i\theta/2}$, $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$.

Comment: so this would not be true, there is the function you showed which is injective and not continuous and not surjective, am I right?

Comment: Yes, $e^{-i\pi/2} \notin \text{Im}(f)$, and $f$ is injective. So $f$ is not continuous (more precisely, not continuous at $z = 1$).
But if you drop continuity assumptions there are lot of pathological examples, for example take any incountable subset $A \subset S^1$ and any bijection $f: S^1 \to A$, this is an example of an injective but not surjective function.

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is no. Suppose $f:S^1 \to S^1$ is continuous injective but not surjective. Then the image of $f$ is a connected compact subset of $S^1$ that's properly contained in $S^1$. In particular, its image is homeomorphic to a closed interval. But then $f$ is a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space, and hence a homeomorphism, a contradiction.

In general, however, it's possible to find such functions. Take the real line for example. A homeomorphism to an open interval should do the trick.

Comment: Ah oops, didn't see the other answer

Comment: it happens, +1 for adding more details than my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

For a compact orientable $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ you need to use the following two facts: (1) the homology group $H_n(M)$ is nontrivial; (2) the homology group $H_n(M\setminus\{pt\})=0$ where $pt$ is a single point. Therefore there are no injective nonsurjective continuous maps from $M$ to itself.