# Injective and continuous function from circle to circle $\psi:S^{1} \rightarrow S^{1}$, homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

I was wondering that if I got a function $\psi:S^{1} \rightarrow S^{1}$ which is continous and injective, can it be a homeomorphism? From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2320879/fs1-rightarrow-s1-injective-but-not-surjective) I know that at least $\psi$ is bijective. But what I haven't been able to prove is that in fact $\psi^{-1}$ is continous.

Any idea on how to prove that fact? Thanks so much.

Comment: Obviously it *can* be, take the identity. Is your question whether it *must* be? Carefully reading the answer you link tells you that the answer is yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show that $\psi^{-1}$ is continuous, you must show that for every open set $U\subseteq S^1$ we have $\psi(U)$ open.

This is equivalent to showing that for every closed set $V\subseteq S^1$, $\psi(V)$ is closed.

As $S^1$ is compact, any closed $V\subseteq S^1$ is compact.  The image of a compact set under a continuous map is also compact, so $\psi(V)$ is compact.

Finally, as $S^1$ is Hausdorf, any compact set is closed.  Thus $\psi(V)$ is closed as required.

In fact, this argument proves the general result: [A continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorf space is always a homeomorphism.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Bijection_from_Compact_to_Hausdorff_is_Homeomorphism#:%7E:text=Since%20T1%20is%20compact,of%20Compact%20Space%20is%20Compact.&text=From%20Continuity%20Defined%20from%20Closed,definition%2C%20f%20is%20a%20homeomorphism.)